# Why does Spring run a @Scheduled method when the bean is declared via XML, but not when the bean is discovered through annotation?

Tags: spring, scala

I'd like a task to run every 10 seconds. When I declare the Bean in my `applicationContext.xml` file, everything works as expected. When I simply annotate the Bean with `@Component`, the task never executes. My code/config looks like the following:

`QueueProcessor.scala`

```
package example.components

// imports removed for brevity

@Component
class QueueProcessor {

  @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 10000)
  def poll() = {
    println("polling queue")
  }

}
```

`applicationContext.xml`

```
<context:component-scan base-package="example.components" />
<task:executor id="genericExecutor" pool-size="2" />
<task:scheduler id="genericScheduler" pool-size="2" />
<task:annotation-driven executor="genericExecutor" scheduler="genericScheduler" />
```

If I simply add a line with `<bean id="queueProcessor" class="example.components.QueueProcessor" />`, to my `applicationContext.xml`, then the task executes every 10 seconds as expected. I've verified that other classes in the `example.components` package are being instantiated via annotation, so this class not being discovered shouldn't be the issue.

Any ideas as to what else might be wrong?

EDIT: I moved the line `<task:annotation-driven executor="genericExecutor" scheduler="genericScheduler" />` to my `servlet.xml` file. That solved the problem. Does this have to do with the order in which the files are read?

Comment: Do you have multiple Spring context files by any chance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the edited question, moving the line `<task:annotation-driven executor="genericExecutor" scheduler="genericScheduler" />` to the `servlet.xml` file resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue really perplexes me. I have a working example with an almost identical setup. It seems like it is not getting picked up as a Spring bean when you use annotation. Can you inject a dependency into your QueueProcessor class via annotation and see if that works? That will at least tell us if it is being picked up appropriately as a Spring bean.

Comment: Yep, injecting a dependency worked. I'll add this in an edit, but I found that placing the `<task:annotation-driven />` line in my servlet file fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

To make annotation works try to add following line:

```
<context:annotation-config/>
```

This should do the trick.

See also: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-annotation-config

Comment: Even component-scan does the same thing - reigstering an `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` - and the xml already has a component-scan, so I doubt if this will help.